# Creating regular notification in Blackberry Notification bar

Tags: blackberry, notifications

I've read a little on Blackberry push notifications, but I'm not sure if the code provided is what I'm trying to achieve. Basically, I want my application to have a notification popup after a period of time, with an icon and a message, and once they have clicked on that notifcation it takes the user to the relevant class, and removes the notification. I can do this in Android rather easily however I have not found what I want for Blackberry. I've implemented my timer code, so that's no problem, but I would like someone to point me to a tutorial or in the right direction. The notification should popup in the notification bar (shown below) and in the notification screen (also shown below).

I've tried code like this, but had no success:

```
ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();    

                                    EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("logosmall.png");

                                    ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon( image );

                                    ApplicationIndicator indicator = reg.register( icon, false, true);
                                    indicator.setIcon(icon);
                                    indicator.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Jack
I've also now tried this:

```
public ApplicationIndicator _indicator; 
public static handleGPSListener _instance;

public void setupIndicator() {

    //Setup notification 
    if (_indicator == null) {
        ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
        _indicator = reg.getApplicationIndicator();

        if(_indicator == null) {
            ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon(EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource ("daslogo.png"));
            _indicator = reg.register(icon, false, true);  
            _indicator.setValue(0);
            _indicator.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}

public void setVisible(boolean visible, int count) {

    if (_indicator != null) {
        if (visible) {
            _indicator.setVisible(true);
            _indicator.setValue(count);
        } else {
            _indicator.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}

handleGPSListener () {

}

public static handleGPSListener getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new handleGPSListener ();
    }
    return(_instance);
}
```

And I call the setupIndicator method from another void method below:

```
public void LocationUpdate(){
setupIndicator();
}
```

Here's the whole class if it helps also:

```
package mypackage;

import javax.microedition.location.Coordinates;
import javax.microedition.location.Location;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationException;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationListener;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;

import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIcon;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIndicator;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIndicatorRegistry;
 import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationMessageFolder;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Cursor;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Database;
import net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseFactory;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Row;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Statement;
import net.rim.device.api.io.URI;
import net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor;
import net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;

public class handleGPSListener implements LocationListener {
Coordinates c = null;
private double lat=0.00;
private double lon=0.00;
Database sqliteDB;
String username;
public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public String URL = "http://77.245.77.195:60010/Webservice/IDLMobile.asmx?WSDL";
public static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org   /Get_OfferCount_By_Location";
public static final String METHOD_NAME = "Get_OfferCount_By_Location";
private double x,y;
public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider loc, Location location) {  //method to update as the location changes.
    System.out.println("class handle GPS Listener");
    if (loc == null) {  //condition to check if the location information is null.
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("GPS not supported!"); //dialog box to alert gps is not started.
                System.out.println("Problem 1");
                return;
            }
        });
    } else {    //if not checked.
        System.out.println("OK");
        switch (loc.getState()) {   //condition to check state of the location.
        case (LocationProvider.AVAILABLE):  //condition to check if the location is available.

            System.out.println("Provider is AVAILABLE");

            try {
                location = loc.getLocation(-1); //location to get according to user present.
            } catch (LocationException e) {
                return;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (location != null && location.isValid()) {   //condition to check if the location is not null and is valid.
                c = location.getQualifiedCoordinates(); //to get the coordinates of the location.
            }
            if (c != null) {    //condition to check if the location is not null.
                lat = c.getLatitude();  //retrieve the latitude values into variable.
                lon = c.getLongitude(); //retrieve the longitude values into variable.
                System.out.println("lat and lon"+lat+lon);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(
                        new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                updateFields();
                                getValues();
                                // Dialog.alert(lat+"GPS supported!"+lon);
                                return;
                            }

                            private void getValues() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {
                                    URI uri = URI
                                            .create("file:///SDCard/"
                                                    + "database3.db");  //database3 to retrieve the values from location table.
                                    sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
                                    Statement st = null;
                                    st = sqliteDB
                                            .createStatement("SELECT Latitude,Longitude FROM Location");//statement to retrieve the lat and lon values.
                                    st.prepare();
                                    Cursor c = st.getCursor();//cursor to point.
                                    Row r;
                                    int i = 0;
                                    while (c.next()) {  //loop to execute until there are no values in the cursor.
                                        r = c.getRow(); //store the values in row.
                                        i++;
                                        lat=Double.parseDouble(r.getString(0)); //retrieve the latitude values from the database and store in variable.
                                        lon=Double.parseDouble(r.getString(1)); //retrieve the longitude values from the database and store in variable.
                                        System.out.println(r.getString(0)
                                                + " Latitude");
                                        System.out.println(r.getString(1)
                                                + " Longitude");

                                    }

                                    st.close();
                                    sqliteDB.close();
                                }

                                catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println(e.getMessage()
                                            + " wut");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                    URI uri = URI
                                            .create("file:///SDCard/"
                                                    + "database1.db");
                                    sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
                                    Statement st = null;
                                    st = sqliteDB
                                            .createStatement("SELECT Name FROM People");
                                    st.prepare();
                                    Cursor c = st.getCursor();
                                    Row r;
                                    int i = 0;
                                    while (c.next()) {
                                        r = c.getRow();
                                        i++;
                                        username=r.getString(0);

                                        System.out.println(r.getString(0)
                                                + "Name");


                                    }

                                    st.close();
                                    sqliteDB.close();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                                rpc.addProperty("Username", username);
                                rpc.addProperty("latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
                                rpc.addProperty("longitude", String.valueOf(lon));
                                rpc.addProperty("distance", "1.5");
                                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                                envelope.bodyOut = rpc;
                                envelope.dotNet = true;
                                envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;

                                HttpTransport ht = new HttpTransport(URL);
                                ht.debug = true;

                                try {
                                    ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                                    System.out.println("IN TRY");
                                    SoapObject resultProperties = (SoapObject) envelope
                                            .getResponse();

                                    System.out.println("username INT RIGHT HERE " + resultProperties.getProperty(0));
                                    System.out.println("username INT RIGHT HERE " + resultProperties.getProperty(1).toString());
                                    System.out.println("username INT RIGHT HERE " + resultProperties.getProperty(2).toString());
                                    System.out.println("lat and lon PARSE HERE " + lat+"\n"+lon);

                                    /* here is the notification code */

                                    //ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();    

                                    //EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("logosmall.png");

                                    //ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon( image );

                                    //ApplicationIndicator indicator = reg.register( icon, false, true);
                                    //indicator.setIcon(icon);
                                    //indicator.setVisible(true);

                                    setupIndicator();

                                    /* end notification code */


                                } catch (org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException ex2) {

                                } catch (Exception ex) {

                                    String bah = ex.toString();

                                }
                            }

                            private void updateFields() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {

                                    URI myURI = URI
                                            .create("file:///SDCard/"
                                                    + "database3.db");
                                    sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
                                    Statement st = null;
                                    Statement oops = null;
                                    st = sqliteDB
                                    .createStatement("SELECT Latitude,Longitude FROM Location");
                            st.prepare();
                            Cursor c = st.getCursor();
                            Row r;
                            int i = 0;
                            while (c.next()) {
                                r = c.getRow();
                                i++;
                                x=Double.parseDouble(r.getString(0));
                                y=Double.parseDouble(r.getString(1));
                                System.out.println(r.getString(0)
                                        + " Latitude in update fields");
                                System.out.println(r.getString(1)
                                        + " Longitude in update fields");

                            }
                                    st = sqliteDB
                                            .createStatement("UPDATE Location SET Latitude='"
                                                    + lat
                                                    + "' "
                                                    + "WHERE Latitude="
                                                    + "'" + x + "'" + "");
                                    oops = sqliteDB
                                            .createStatement("UPDATE Location SET Longitude='"
                                                    + lon
                                                    + "' "
                                                    + "WHERE Longitude="
                                                    + "'" + y + "'" + "");
                                    System.out.println("location updated");
                                    System.out
                                            .println("lat and lon values are"
                                                    + lat + lon);
                                    st.prepare();
                                    oops.prepare();
                                    st.execute();
                                    oops.execute();
                                    st.close();
                                    oops.close();
                                    sqliteDB.close();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });
            }

        }
    }
}

public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) {
    if (newState == LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE) {
        // GPS unavailable due to IT policy specification
        System.out.println("GPS unavailable due to IT policy specification");
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("GPS unavailable due to IT policy specification");

                return;
            }
        });
    } else if (newState == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE) {
        // no GPS fix
        System.out.println("GPS temporarily unavailable due to IT policy specification");
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("no GPS fix");
                return;
            }
        });
    }

}


public ApplicationIndicator _indicator; 
public static handleGPSListener _instance;

public void setupIndicator() {

    //Setup notification 
    if (_indicator == null) {
        ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
        _indicator = reg.getApplicationIndicator();

        if(_indicator == null) {
            ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon(EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource ("daslogo.png"));
            _indicator = reg.register(icon, false, true);  
            _indicator.setValue(0);
            _indicator.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}

public void setVisible(boolean visible, int count) {

    if (_indicator != null) {
        if (visible) {
            _indicator.setVisible(true);
            _indicator.setValue(count);
        } else {
            _indicator.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}

handleGPSListener () {

}

public static handleGPSListener getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new handleGPSListener ();
    }
    return(_instance);
}
```

}

To my understanding I could use this code, however when I do it says `Demo message could not be resolved as a type`

```
     //Register the ApplicationMessageFolder
    //ReadableListImpl source is available in the messagelistdemo.
       ApplicationMessageFolder folder =       ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance().registerFolder(
0x33c7ce29883abe5fL, "Test Folder", new ReadableListImpl());

    //DemoMessage source is available in the messagelistdemo.
      DemoMessage msg = new DemoMessage("me@here.com", "Pizza Toppings", 
"What would you like on your pizza?", System.currentTimeMillis());
      folder.fireElementAdded(msg);

    //Display the application indicator icon.
      ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();    

    EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("Indicator.png");

    ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon(image);

    ApplicationIndicator indicator = reg.register(icon, false, true);
    indicator.setIcon(icon);
    indicator.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Just wanted to say "thanks", I have been looking for the classes that control the Indicator/Notification messages for awhile but could not come up with the correct names to search for!

Comment: My pleasure! We're all in it together!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can click on the icon to take you to the app. My understanding is that it works only for in built apps like facebook etc.

But to show the indicator try this

```java
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIcon;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIndicator;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.messagelist.ApplicationIndicatorRegistry;
import net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage; 

public class MyAppIndicator{


    public ApplicationIndicator _indicator; 
    public static MyAppIndicator _instance; 
    private MyAppIndicator () {

    }

    public static MyAppIndicator getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new MyAppIndicator ();
        }
        return(_instance);
    }

    public void setupIndicator() {

        //Setup notification 
        if (_indicator == null) {
            ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
            _indicator = reg.getApplicationIndicator();

            if(_indicator == null) {
                ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon(EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource ("status_icon_24x24.png"));
                _indicator = reg.register(icon, false, true);  
                _indicator.setValue(0);
                _indicator.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible, int count) {

        if (_indicator != null) {
            if (visible) {
                _indicator.setVisible(true);
                _indicator.setValue(count);
            } else {
                _indicator.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok. So say I wanted to call this code when a particular event occurs, in example say a timer reached 100, and now I need to call this code. Do I just call the setupIndicator()?

Comment: Yes, just call the code when you need to and it should set up the indicator. Let me know if it works/doesn work :-)

Comment: No problem I'm implementing it now, give me a little but :>

Comment: Still not working. I've put the code in the above answer, and even supplied the whole class.

Comment: setupIndicator() will set up the indicator. If you want to make it visible, call setvisible ()

Comment: I call setupIndicator(); then I call setVisible(true, 0); but it still shows no notification.